# Error showing when using Custom repository in Symfony 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I am new to symfony 2. I am trying to use custom repository in symfony 2. After writing the function in the detailsRepository.php file. in the controller I wrote

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
 $products = $em->getRepository('BundlesampleBundle:details')
            ->findAllWhoseEmailContains($value);
```

but i am getting the error as

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symblog\src\Bundle\sampleBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 162 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\symblog\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php line 61 (500 Internal Server Error)

My detailsRepository.php is as follows

```
<?php

namespace Bundle\sampleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * detailsRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */

class detailsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllWhoseEmailContains($value)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('Select e.email from BundlesampleBundle:details e Where  e.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email',$value)
            ->getResult();


    }   

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put all necessary annotations to all classes, like it's said here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html ?
Are you using latest Symfony 2.0.5?

Comment: hai... thanks for the responce... i have updated the question  with the contents in my detailsRepository.php file

Comment: sorry forgot to mention... am using symfony 2.0.5.

Comment: @Philemon Have you annotated your entity class with `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX"`>? Also a namespace for your bundles named "Bundle" looks strange. Why didn't you call it `Philemon` for example?

Comment: hai FractalizeR, sorry i could not understand this " @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX" " is this a automatically generated when i build class. please explain.

Comment: Look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: In version >= 3.3, the documentation is now here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html