# Class repository doesn't work in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, repository

It's my code:

file <kbd>Entity/Article.php</kbd>

```
namespace Kaker\FormularzBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Kaker\FormularzBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
 class Article {...}
```

file Entity/ArticleRepository:

```
namespace Kaker\FormularzBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getNickInfo($nick)
    {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a FROM KakerFormularzBundle:Article a WHERE a.nick = :nick '
        )
        ->setParameter('nick', $nick)
        ->getResult();
    }
}
```

file UserController

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$article = $em->getRepository("KakerFormularzBundle:Article")
            ->getNickInfo($nick);
```

And I have this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in /var/www/apps/sf2-podstwy/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1496 and defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error showing when using Custom repository in Symfony 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075258/error-showing-when-using-custom-repository-in-symfony-2)

Comment: Are your sure you are not trying to new ArticleRepository somewhere?  Perhaps you have it defined as a service and are trying to inject it in something.  Normally, a repository is created with EntityManager::getRepository($entityClassName).  Your particular error message indicates that something is trying to new it directly.

Comment: maybe, in ArticleController i have this code (which working): `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rows = $em->getRepository("KakerFormularzBundle:Article")
                ->getAllArticle();`,but in UserController the same code doesn't work